# MySQL insert_id always returns zero

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm working on editing an old project from php 5.3 to php 7+.
Unpleasant work, but I have to do it with minimal changes to the code.

I came across the following problem.
The insert_id always returns 0.

I have read that this may be because I do not have an auto_increment key on the table or the last query wasn't an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement but my problem is not due to this. The request successfully inputs information into the database.

This is the code:

```
class DBTable{

 function connection(){
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'db');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        exit();
    }
    return $mysqli;
  }

  function addrow_id($row){
    $query="some INSERT query";
    $res = $this->connection()->query($query);
    if ($res) $response = $this->connection()->insert_id; //always returns zero    
    return $response;
  }
}
```

I am quite aware that this is not a good `PHP` but I can not start the project from a new one and my task is just to do it to work with **PHP 7+**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->connection()` returns a ***new connection*** every time. Insert ids are specific to the connection, otherwise you'd get interference from parallel clients. You need to reuse your connection object:

```
$query="some INSERT query";
$con = $this->connection();
$res = $con->query($query);
if ($res) $response = $con->insert_id;
```

Preferably you'd do `$this->con = $this->connection()` once in `__construct` and reuse the same connection throughout your object; or, better, you inject one connection you have established globally as dependency when instantiating your object:

```
$con = new mysqli(...);
$db = new DBTable($con);
```

Otherwise you have a lot of overhead establishing and tearing down connections constantly. Not to mention testability and so on with a hardcoded connection.

Comment: @stefo91, Just to add one more point, better you use [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for implementing `connection()` method.

Comment: No, actually better switch to *dependency injection*, as edited in.

Answer (score 1):

I directly used the code from your post, though the answer above is great too.

```html
<?php
class DBTable{
  private $dbcon;

  function __construct() {  //this constructor is called when you do $var = new DBTable() to instantiate your object

    //create the connection and assign it to the dbcon var
    $this->dbcon = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');

    //throw connection error and die
    if ($this->dbcon->connect_error) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $this->$dbcon->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    //throw mysql error and die
    if (!$this->dbcon->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $this->$dbcon->error);
        exit();
    }
  }

  //I add a row and return an ID
  function addrow_id(){
    //create your query string
    $query="INSERT INTO TEST() VALUES()";
    //run the query
    $res = $this->dbcon->query($query);
    if ($res){  //if this value evaluates to zero, we want to throw an error
      $response = $this->dbcon->insert_id;
    } else {  //throw an error, because the query came back with a negative val
      $error = 'When adding a row, I got no results or a value that php interpolates as negative';
      throw new Exception($error);
    }
    //return the new id
    return $response;
  }
}
//instantiate your object/class
$dbTable = new DBTable();
//dump the outcome of your adding a row
var_dump($dbTable->addrow_id());
?>
```